# How do I get more detailed info about the assembly?

Tags: assembly

```
40087e:       48 8b 05 cb 01 20 00    mov    0x2001cb(%rip),%rax        # 600a50 <__CTOR_LIST__+0x8>
```

The above is from output of objdump.

However I want to know which part of `48 8b 05 cb 01 20 00` represents `mov` , `0x2001cb(%rip)` ...

That is,is there a tool to break down the machine code?

Comment: Don't bother answering this question. new_perl will delete the question after he gets you to spend time on his problem! Thanks, bud!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 48 8b 05 cb 01 20 00    mov    0x2001cb(%rip),%rax

48 is the `REX prefix` that is typically used to indicate that instruction operands (registers or memory locations) should be 64-bit instead 32-bit (i.e. RAX instead of EAX in this instruction). REX prefixes are also used in instructions manipulating the R8 through R15 registers.

`8b` is the MOV instruction `opcode`. Other values are used for other instructions. For example, 2b would mean SUB and 8d would mean LEA.

`05` is the `ModR/M` byte that in the 64-bit mode denotes the `RIP+disp32` memory addressing (instead of just `disp32` in the 32-bit mode). This is encoded in the `Mod` and `R/M` bit fields of the byte. This byte's `Reg` bit field additionally tells to use the RAX register for the other operand.

`cb, 01, 20 and 00` form the `disp32` part of the memory operand and this displacement is equal to `2001CBH`.

Putting it all together we arrive at `MOV RAX, [RIP+2001CBH]`.

There are several ways to decode instructions:

- by hand using the CPU manuals from Intel or AMD
- with a standalone disassembler, e.g. `ndisasm` that comes together with [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/)
- with your favorite debugger; just have the bytes of the instruction of interest somewhere in the programs memory (you can type them in) and ask the disassembler to show you the disassembly of that instruction's location